# Can Scala case classes match in both an inherited and non-inherited function?

Tags: scala, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, case-class

Working through the [Essential Scala](https://books.underscore.io/essential-scala/essential-scala.html) book, I find myself playing with the linked list example. I have wound up with a situation where I have a superclass, for lists of anything, and a subclass for lists of `Int`s. I can ask for the length of either type of list, and the sum of a list of ints. However, I am having some trouble modelling this using case classes. The natural inheritance structure is as follows:

```text
         List
     ↙    ↓    ↘
Pair   IntList   End
 ↓    ↙       ↘   ↓
IntPair       IntEnd
```

In List, I would like to be able to match on `Pair` VS `End` in `List`, which I can do by making Pair and End case classes. I use it in the sum function like this:

```scala
  final def length(counter: Int=0): Int =
    this match {
      case Pair(_, tail:List[A]) => tail.length(counter+1)
      case End() => counter
```

However, I would like to be able to match on `IntPair` VS `IntEnd` in `IntList` too. The natural implementation in IntList looks like this:

```scala
  final def sum(counter: Int=0): Int =
    this match {
      case IntPair(head, tail) => tail.sum(head + counter)
      case IntEnd() => counter
```

However, because `Pair` is already a case object, `IntPair` cannot be one too. But if it is not, then we can't match in `sum`. If we don't inherit, then `length` stops working because the match case doesn't know about `IntPair`/`IntEnd`.

I've made a [Github gist with the full Scala worksheet](https://gist.github.com/DDR0/022f1b468ad028ae3fda561b479cbf15), if that is of help. It can be run with `scala -nc inheritance.sc`.

What approach should I take instead of this one?

Comment: You can use implicit evidence to module this without inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is actually pretty good to show why traditional sub-type polymorphism *(usually modelled thought inheritance on OOP languages)* is not enough to naturally implement some use cases.

So lets take a look to other alternatives. In this case, I will cover: **implicit evidence**, **extension methods** and **typeclasses** *(which is like a more powerful and flexible combination of the previous two)*.

First lets put a common definition a **List**.

```
sealed trait MyList[+A] extends Product with Serializable {
  final def :!:[B >: A](b: B): MyList[B] = new :!:(b, this)

  final def length: Int = {
    @annotation.tailrec
    def loop(remaining: MyList[A], acc: Int): Int =
      remaining match {
        case _ :!: tail => loop(remaining = tail, acc + 1)
        case MyNil => acc
      }
    loop(remaining = this, acc = 0)
  }
}
final case class :!:[+A](head: A, tail: MyList[A]) extends MyList[A]
final case object MyNil extends MyList[Nothing]
```

### Implicit evidence.

The idea is simple, a **List** provides a `sum` method as long as its elements are **Ints**.
That is the intuition and we can just encode that:

```
sealed trait MyList[+A] extends Product with Serializable {
  // ...

  // B required due variance.
  final def sum[B >: A](implicit ev: B =:= Int): Int = {
    @annotation.tailrec
    def loop(remaining: MyList[B], acc: Int): Int =
      remaining match {
        case i :!: tail => loop(remaining = tail, acc + i)
        case MyNil => acc
      }
    loop(remaining = this, acc = 0)
  }
}
```

This encoding allows us to call `sum` on any **List** as long as the compiler can prove that the elements of that **List** are **Ints**, if not the method won't be available.

### Extension methods.

We can accomplish exactly the same behaviour as the **implicit evidence** by adding `sum` as an **extension method** for **Lists** of **Ints** only.
This can be helpful if you do not control the datatype, or even if you control it but you have a lot of methods that require some conditions so you can split the code into multiple files, and even allow the user to opt-in for those extensions.

```
implicit class IntListOps(private val intList: MyList[Int]) extends AnyVal {
  def sum: Int = {
    @annotation.tailrec
    def loop(remaining: MyList[Int], acc: Int): Int =
      remaining match {
        case i :!: tail => loop(remaining = tail, acc + i)
        case MyNil => acc
      }
    loop(remaining = intList, acc = 0)
  }
}
```

Just as before, this encoding allows us to call the `sum` method into any **List** as long as the compiler can prove that the elements of the **List** are **Ints** *(and that the extension method is in scope, usually through an `import`)*.

## Typeclasses

Finally, one of the most powerful patterns of Functional Programming languages, the [**typeclasses**](https://tpolecat.github.io/2013/10/12/typeclass.html).

In this case, we would need to add a lot of *"boilerplate"* code, as well as using **extension methods**. However, it must be noted that this allows us to extend this `sum` method to work on ant type that is summable, like **Double** or **BigInt**.

```
trait Summable[A] {
  def sum(a1: A, a2: A): A
  def zero: A
}

object Summable {
  implicit final val IntSummable: Summable[Int] =
    new Summable[Int] {
      override def sum(i1: Int, i2: Int): Int = i1 + i2
      override val zero: Int = 0
    }
  
  object syntax {
    implicit class SummableOps[A](private val a1: A) extends AnyVal {
      @inline final def |+|(a2: A)(implicit ev: Summable[A]): A = ev.sum(a1, a2)
    }
    
    implicit class SummableListOps[A](private val list: MyList[A]) extends AnyVal {
      @inline final def sum(implicit ev: Summable[A]): A = {
        @annotation.tailrec
        def loop(remaining: MyList[A], acc: A): A =
          remaining match {
            case i :!: tail => loop(remaining = tail, acc |+| i)
            case MyNil => acc
          }
        loop(remaining = list, acc = ev.zero)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Again, the compiler will allow us to call `sum` on a **List** as long as it can prove that their elements are summable. And, since the [implicit scope](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-implicits.html) is quite flexible, you can easily make custom types **Summable**.

Also, we could even generalize this even more, what about we provide `sum` on any type that can be iterated on?
This is exactly what [**cats**](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses.html) does, it provides *(between another amount of very useful things)* two abstractions **Monoid** *(which is the mathematical name for **Summable**)* and `Foldable` *(which represents the possibility of iterating something)*, which combined give us the `combineAll` method *(and may other powerful abstractions like `foldMap`)* on any *"collection"* of *"combinable"* elements.

---

While each of those techniques is powerful on its own, the real power of **Scala** is that it allows you to mix them to get the API you desire.
For example, the std **List** provides the `sum` method using an **implicit evidence** but of the existence of a **typeclass**.

Also, there are other kinds of polymorphism techniques like **duck typing *(structural types)***, which I personally do not like but it's helpful to known about it.
In case you are interested, I once [wrote](https://gist.github.com/BalmungSan/c19557030181c0dc36533f3de7d7abf4) about some of those techniques and their differences in **Scala**.

---

*You can see the full code [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/ADKtd5NeQyqfoEkYYhE6pQ/11)*

Answer (score 2):

You can define your own extractor instead of using case classes. That's how you can use both match and inheritance.

To define an extractor you mast specify *unapply* method in your object, like that;

```
object IntPair {
  def unapply(intPair: IntPair): Option[(Int, Int)] = Some(intPair._1, IntPair._2)
}
```

for more information:
https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/extractor-objects.html

Comment: Thank you, Greg. I'm a total beginner here, and this was honestly the only answer I understood. 

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to solve this. It all depends on where you're willing to compromise in order to achieve your goals.

If you want `IntPair` to have both `.length` and `.sum` then one solution is to inherit from both traits.

```
case class IntPair(...) extends Pair(head,tail) with IntList
```

But that doesn't work because `case class`-to-`case class` inheritance is not allowed.

So in order to inherit from `Pair` it can't be a `case` class, but we don't have to give up all the nice features of a `case class`, we just have to code those in.

```
sealed class End[A]() extends List[A]
object End {
  def apply[A](): End[A] = new End()
  def unapply[A](arg: End[A]): Boolean = true
}
sealed class Pair[A](val head: A, val tail: List[A]) extends List[A]
object Pair {
  def apply[A](head: A, tail: List[A]): Pair[A] = new Pair(head, tail)
  def unapply[A](arg: Pair[A]): Option[(A, List[A])] =
    Some((arg.head, arg.tail))
}
```

With that in place we can create the desired inheritance.

```
final case class IntEnd() extends End[Int]() with IntList
final case class IntPair(override val head: Int
                        ,override val tail: IntList
                        ) extends Pair(head,tail) with IntList
```

Now the test assertions will pass.

```
val example = IntPair(1, IntPair(2, IntPair(3, IntEnd())))
assert(example.sum() == 6)
assert(example.tail.sum() == 5)
assert(IntEnd().sum() == 0)
assert(example.length() == 3)
assert(IntEnd().length() == 0)
```